# Converting spaghetti code to Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Need to convert script with "spaghetti code" to Twig. Read Twig documentation and got basics working. However, I need advice on how to do everything properly, so no re-conversion is needed later. Let's say current script looks following:

file index.php:

```
<?php
$page_message="do it";

function display_dropdown($max)
    {
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
        {
        echo "<option value='$i'>Option $i</option>";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $page_message; ?></h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]); ?>">
<select name="whatever"><?php display_dropdown(10); ?></select>
<input type="submit" value="go">
<?php include("footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

footer.php looks:

```
<?php
$footer_text="blah blah";
?>
<footer><?php echo $footer_text; ?></footer>
```

As far I understand, my index.php should look like this when converted to Twig:

```
<?php
$page_message="do it";

function display_dropdown($max)
    {
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
        {
        echo "<option value='$i'>Option $i</option>";
        }
    }



$twig_params_array=array("page_message"=>$page_message, "footer_text"=>"blah blah");

require_once("../lib/Twig/Autoloader.php");
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader=new Twig_Loader_Filesystem("templates");
$twig=new Twig_Environment($loader);


echo $twig->render("index_template.html", $twig_params_array);
?>
```

Then I should create `index_template.html` and `footer_template.html` (or whatever) with following code:

index_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>{{ page_message }}</h1>
<form method="post" action="{{ _self }}>">
<select name="whatever"><?php display_dropdown(10); ?></select>
<input type="submit" value="go">
{{ include('footer_template.html') }}
</body>
</html>
```

footer_template.html

```
<footer>{{ footer_text }}</footer>
```

If I understand right, it's also possible to "include" functions in Twig templates (with some tweaking in templates), so I don't need to rewrite existing PHP functions like `display_dropdown()`. Because dropdown is not displayed at the moment...

The thing that concerns me is array with variables (passed to Twig `render` function). Do I miss something, or is it really needed to manually define each variable (like `$page_message` and `$footer_text`) before Twig can work?

It seems like a lot of work to do, because in "spaghetti code" if I define variable somewhere, I can access it at any time just by using `echo` function. Now, it looks I need to view every single variable that exists in PHP code and manually pass it to Twig parameters array. Really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no solution was provided, I found it myself. All you have to do is use such a line of code, so all the variables you have in your PHP file (counting included files) become available in Twig templates, and you don't need to re-write anything when new variables are added to PHP file later (they also automatically become available in Twig):

```
echo $twig->render("template_file_name.extension", get_defined_vars());
```

Comment: can you share more about how you did this? I'm trying to do the same, but didn't quite follow your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Mindaugas, just changing the technology you use to render views is not going to make the code less tangled.

I think you should go one step further and divide responsibilities, by using an MVC framework, like Symfony, which uses Twig as its default templating language.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't have an urgent need to use Symfony framework now, but converting current script to Twig really made a difference already.